# Customvalidator OnServerValidate event never triggered

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I am trying to create a customvalidator to check if an email is already in the database at the point of an user registration. I have seen many similar questions dealing with customvalidators but no answer has brought any avail.

I have simplified the OnServerValidate method to always return false to get ANY sort of response but I am not getting any response. I believe that the method is never being fired. I have come to some conclusion there is some other issue that is effecting the triggering of the event.

Here is the ASP which is inside a contentplaceholder within the master page. There is also a scriptmanager in the master file.

<%--email and confirm email--%>

```
                        <td>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkEmail" runat="server" TargetControlID="Email" WatermarkText="Email" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Columns="48" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation" CausesValidation="True"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Email" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CheckEmail" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="This email already is registered." ValidateEmptyString="true"  display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Email" runat="server" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" OnServerValidate="checkEmailValidator_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkConfirmEmail" runat="server" TargetControlID="ConfirmEmail" WatermarkText="Confirm Email" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmEmail" runat="server" Columns="48" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail" ErrorMessage="Confirm E-mail is required." ToolTip="Confirm E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And then the server-side script. This has a breakpoint at every line and NONE of them are ever getting hit. So I am assuming that the method is never getting triggered.....

```
protected void checkEmailValidator_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;

        }
```

And here is the button to move to the next part of the form. It merely just hides one div and shows another to continue the registration process.

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="NextButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/registration/arrowright.png" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="False" OnClientClick="return false;" 
            Height="50px" onmouseover="this.src='images/registration/arrowrightgreen.png'" 
            onmouseout="this.src='images/registration/arrowright.png'" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
```

This button is used to move to a second part of the registration process, which I use jQuery for. This is why the `OnClientClick="return false;"` line is there so the jQuery will run correctly. Is there anywhere around this?

```
   $("[id$=NextButton]").click(function (e) {
        //alert(Page_ClientValidate("UserInformation"));
        if (Page_ClientValidate("UserInformation")) {
        $("[id$=pick_user_type]").css('position', 'absolute');
        $("[id$=registration_div]").css('position', 'absolute');
            $("[id$=registration_div]").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);           
            $("[id$=pick_user_type]").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define the validator group of a validator than you to also define the validation group of Controls which the validator is validating.
So define your textbox like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Columns="48" CssClass="roundedcorner"
ValidationGroup="UserInformation"
></asp:TextBox>
```

If you didnt define the validation group of your button than define there validation group too/

**Edit**

`OnClientClick="return false;"` remove this line to make your button postback. If you dont remoove than your form never submited means it will never send request on server.

Comment: Strange that that was left out. I had it there at one point, maybe deleted it out of desperation. I have added it back and I have no change. The breakpoints are not being reached.

Comment: did u define the validation group for your button that cause postback i mean sane validation group

Comment: I have edited my post to include the code for the button that validates that group. It contains the ValidationGroup syntax.

Comment: OnClientClick="return false;" remove this line to make your button postback,,,

Comment: That worked! It entered into the region where the breakpoints are. However, it causes issues with my jQuery. This is why I had that line to begin with. I have edited my post. I need this line to execute jQuery. Is there anyway I can have both the postback and execute the jQuery correctly?

Comment: @IanMcCullough server validate of custom validator validates only when the form is submitted there is no other way on thing you can do is use client script of custom validator instead of servervalidatore. and validate on client side.